# Is there an alternative to TCPDF::writeHTML to get inline bold text

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to generate a PDF with text only.

First I've used multiCell to add the text, now I wanted to have two words become bold (somewhere in the middle in my text). So I changed my code to use writeHTML and surrounded i with b-tags, and voila the words are now blod. But at the same time my document size went from 41kB to 205kB which seems a little extreme.

Is there anyway to use inline blod formatting in the text without increasing the PDF size by 300%?

Comment: changing your font to a bold one at the middle of the line does it help?

Comment: Hmm didn't think of that...that might do the trick.

Comment: Ok, I made an answer for that, so you can accept if this works for you :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I said in comments, try with changing your font prior to using `Cell()` or `Multicell()` , example follows:

```
$pdf=new PDF();
...
$pdf->Cell(180,10,'bla bla',0,1,'C');
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',16);            //Change to bold
$pdf->Cell(180,10,'bla bla bla',0,1,'C'); //this printed in bold
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);             //Revert to plain font
$pdf->Cell(180,10,'bla bla bla',0,1,'C');
```

Comment: But it makes 3 cells, problem e.g. when you need border.